# How to get only first 50 files from all subdirectories of a directory in Python?

Tags: python, file, path

I am trying to get first 50 .jpg files from different subdirectories of a particular directory. Till now, I have only succedded in getting the path name of all using the following list of commands:

```
import os
import os.path

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("."):
    for filename in [f for f in filenames if f.endswith(".jpg")]:
        print os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
```

Can someone please tell as to how to extract only first 50 files from the subdirectories?

Comment: Do you want `.log` or `.jpg`?  Your code says `log`, your question description says `jpg`.

Comment: Sorry for that. It's actually .jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the first `n` values of your list comprehension.  If you only want the filename, `split` on `/` and take the last element:

```
import os
import os.path

n = 50
fext = ".jpg"

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("."):
    for filename in [f for f in filenames if f.endswith(fext)][:n]:
        print (filename)
```

Comment: if you want the filename; just `print(filename)`

Comment: Yes, that's very true.

Answer (score 0):

Use `os.listdir` to list file and directories.

Use `os.path.isdir` to get directories.

The following code gets fullpath of 50 '.jpg's files in each subdirectories.

```
target_dir = os.path.abspath('.')

sub_dir_list = [os.path.join(target_dir, one_dir) for one_dir in os.listdir(target_dir) if
            os.path.isdir(os.path.join(target_dir, one_dir))]

img_file_list = []
for sub_dir in sub_dir_list:
    img_file_list.extend([one_file for one_file in os.listdir(sub_dir) if one_file.endswith('.jpg')][:50])
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way would be to avoid to

- create a `list` comprehension
- slice it using naive slicing `[:50]`

that creates 2 useless lists and is not that performant.

I would suggest to generate the names using a generator comprehension rather than list comprehension, and use `islice` on it. Like that no temporary list is created. Only works with 1 value at a time:

```
import itertools,os

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("."):
    for filename in itertools.islice((f for f in filenames if f.endswith(".jpg")),50):
        print(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
```

also be careful: some weird filesystems won't necessarily sort the files by name, maybe you'll need to first sort the list, then slice.

```
for filename in itertools.islice(sorted([f for f in filenames if f.endswith(".jpg")]),50):
```